# Generating Public/Private Bitcoin Keys

Tags: python, cryptography, blockchain, bitcoin

I came across the [following code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185106/bitcoin-wallet-address-and-private-key-generator) for generating public/private key pairs in python for the Bitcoin blockchain.

Are there any other ways *(libraries)* to to do this? *(Google came up fruitless in my attempts to find one. `python-bitcoinlib` seems interesting but I didn't quite understand the documentation)*

What other crypto currencies, that are forks of the Bitcoin code base, can use this same way of generating key pairs? *(i.e. can this code be used to generate addresses for Dash, Pivx and their derivatives?)*

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found an answer in [moneywagon](https://github.com/priestc/moneywagon)

```
from moneywagon import generate_keypair
address = generate_keypair('btc', 'some-random-string')
print(address)
```